# Windows Server 2012 R2 - Error: Server Manager is collecting inventory data. The wizard will be available after data collection finishes

Tags: windows, powershell, server, iis-8

I am getting the following error when I try to open my Server Manager Roles under Windows Server 2012 R2:

```
Server Manager is collecting inventory data. The wizard will be available after data collection finishes.
```

[image: Screenshot of error: Server Manager is collecting inventory data. The wizard will be available after data collection finishes.]

After I click the OK button nothing happens, so I try to open the All Servers list and see the following error:

```
 Refresh failed. More...

 Configuration refresh failed with the following error. the account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process.
```

[image: screenshot of error: Configuration refresh failed with the following error. The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process.]

A Google search leads to the following solutions which do not work and/or are not applicable to Windows Server 2012 and Server Manager:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2478117

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13444.windows-server-2012-server-manager-troubleshooting-guide-part-ii-troubleshoot-manageability-status-errors-in-server-manager.aspx

I have also tried and failed with many errors to AutoRecover from mofcomp as suggested in several web pages such as http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2058623/error-message-add-roles-features-hyper-server-2012-server-manager-collecting-inventory-data.html

I also tried to install Windows features via Powershell and I got the exact same error:

Powershell: Get-WindowsFeature

Error:

```
 Get-WindowsFeature : The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services
 running in the same process.
 At line:1 char:1
 + Get-WindowsFeature
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : DeviceError: (Microsoft.Manag...rDetailsHandle):CimException) [Get-WindowsFeature], Exce
    ption
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnSupportedTargetDevice,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.GetWindowsFeatureComman
    d
```

Does anyone have a working solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Please use try following approach:

open command prompt with **admin** rights and execute it as below:

```
cd C:\Windows\System32\wbem\AutoRecover

for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof *.mfl') do mofcomp %s
```

Once completed you can start Server Manager and start adding roles and features again.

Comment: It worked in my Win Svr 2016 VM - THANK YOU! What does this command do exactly?

Comment: I think that when the WMI is corrupted, the server manager cannot work properly, and the file in autorecover dir, could be used to rebuild the WMI using the mofcomp command